# A hard Ntse stage 1 examination problem

Tags: geometry

In a triangle ABC, D and E are the points on BC and AC, respectively. If AD and BE intersect at the point P such that $\frac{\text{AP}}{\text{DP}}=5$ and $\frac{\text{BP}}{\text{EP}}=7$, then CD:BD=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the situation is as follows:

[image: Theorem of Menelaus, Application]

(In other words, i assume that the point $P$ is in the interior of the triangle, so that in a relation like $AP:DP=5$ the segments have no orientation. Note: In case an orientation would have been given, then for an interior point $P$ the proportion is negative.)

We use the [Theorem of Menelaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem)
for the triangle $\Delta BPD$ with the line $AEC$ intersecting its sides in the mentioned points $A,E,C$. Then:
$$
1 = 
\frac{CB}{CD}\cdot
\frac{AD}{AP}\cdot
\frac{EP}{EB}
 = 
\frac{CB}{CD}\cdot
\frac{6}{5}\cdot
\frac{1}{8}
 = 
\frac{CB}{CD}\cdot
\frac{3}{20}\ .
$$
This gives: 
$$
\frac{CD}{CB}=\frac3{20}\ ,\text{ so }
\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{CD}{CB-CD}=\frac3{20-3}=\frac 3{17}\ .
$$